# Adding a project with a dependency v1 to a project with a dependency v1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependencies

This is the case: I have a project A which has a dependency of a library version 1.0.0.0
It is crucial that this version will remain in this project. For some extra functionality I require to use the library 1.1.0.0, so I have created a class library project with the newer version and added it as a dependency to my main project.
This works fine and complies nicely, but on run time I get an error:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.0.5022.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.0.5022.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at OpenXMLReportsGenerator.GenerateInvoiceFailureReportHEOpenXML.CreatePackage(String filePath, DataSet data, String exporterName)
   at bDoxWebEd.Reports.InvoiceFailureReportHandler.BeginGenerateReportAndSave(Object gerateReportStateInfo)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

When compiling the projects as debug I do not get this error, only when compiling Release.
How can I solve this issue?

Ok after activating function logging on the server I get the following error on my log:

```
Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = IIS APPPOOL\bDoxPool
LOG: DisplayName = DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.0.5022.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/***/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = D:\***\bin
Calling assembly : OpenXMLReportsGenerator, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\Program Files\Nipendo\bDox\bDox\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.0.5022.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/bdox/00aaf85b/66058ca1/DocumentFormat.OpenXml.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/bdox/00aaf85b/66058ca1/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/DocumentFormat.OpenXml.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/***/bin/DocumentFormat.OpenXml.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Build Number
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Comment: Followed the instructions on the end of the message on how to enable binding logging. Then use Fuslogvw.exe to inspect the bindings that fail.

Comment: This only happens in production env, and so I do not have access to the Fuslogvw.exe from the cmd.

Comment: You can copy Fuslogvw.exe to the production computer. If it doesn't work directly, follow the instruction from http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx to turn it on.

Comment: @Panos Rontogiannis thanks for the tip, I have added the logging from the fusion.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `OpenXMLReportsGenerator, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null` references assembly `DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.0.5022.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35`
and the assembly loader cannot locate it.

Try adding this assembly to the bin folder or to the GAC.

Comment: @AMember Then you probably need to add the assemblies to the GAC. Can't you update your question with more details regarding these assemblies. Specify the assemblies and their full name (like DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.0.5022.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35) and their dependencies (referenced assemblies). Also let us know which assemblies are your own and which are third-party.

Comment: I have managed to solve the issue by updating the versions for all of my envs. Thanks for the help any way...